# merge twos rows of table with condition

Tags: mysql

### I have this problem when try to get values and merge rows

### Data

```
Col1------col2-----field-----val
1----------4------content----A
1----------0------content----AZ
1----------4-------title-----B
```

Become

```
Col1----col2----field----val
1---------4-----content---A
1---------0-----title-----B
```

How can i do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to use colspan attribute.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp) there is a web where you could see how to use it properly.